# How to set or install jai plugin on SUSE(Linux)?

Tags: java, netbeans, platform, opensuse, jai

I m fresher and making Desktop APP in netbeans platform in Java SE using SWING technology for Windows, Linux, and MAC OS.In this App we use JAI Library,i made App in widows and then want to run on MAC , and Linux.but before that i have to set or install JAI plugin like jai_imageio-1_1-lib-linux-i586.tar,jai_imageio-1_1-lib-linux-i586-jdk,and jai_imageio-1_1-lib-linux-i586-jre.but i got error for set or install this plugin on SUSE. i also reffer link:[enter link description here](http://download.java.net/media/jai-imageio/builds/release/1.1/INSTALL-jai_imageio.html)

but i cant understod that, how to set first CLASSPATH ?so, any one have idea about that then please suggest me or share your idea with me.
In Advance thanks for your regards.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiary with JAI but as a tip - if it is provided also as jar you could add it to NetBeans jars libraries and that would solve the problem with compilation.